# frama-c : how to assume malloc succeeds?

Tags: frama-c

I would like to analyze my program assuming malloc successfully returns an allocated buffer.

When I run the value plugin with the command

```
/Users/philippeantoine/.opam/4.02.3/bin/frama-c -val testalloc.c
```

on this simple program :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (){
    char * test = malloc(10);
    test[0] = 'a';
}
```

I get the following output :

```
[value] computing for function malloc <- main.
    Called from testalloc.c:4.
[value] using specification for function malloc
[value] Done for function malloc
testalloc.c:5:[kernel] warning: out of bounds write. assert \valid(test+0);
[value] Recording results for main
[value] done for function main
```

I would like not to get the "out of bounds write"
How can I do that ?

PS : I tried to change the malloc specification in stdlib.h, without success

Comment: I think you have to use the provided `malloc` functions. See `stdlib.c` in the `share` directory, and maybe the `-val-builtin` option.

Comment: I do not find any `stdlib.c` file, in the frama-c-Magnesium-20151002 archive. Running with `-val-builtin malloc:Frama_C_alloc_size`I get the error `undeclared builtin 'Frama_C_alloc_size'`

Comment: Sorry, they are not distributed in the Open-Source package. See comments in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466686/frama-c-malloc-neon-20140301-fatal-error

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no satisfying implementation of `malloc` in the current open-source version of Frama-C (in the Value plugin). The previously available versions, in `stdlib.c`, all had drawbacks. They have been removed partly for this reason.

We have implemented a new, sound (correct) and intelligible enough modelization. However, it will only be available with Frama-C Silicium, to be released in october or november 2016.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will be waiting for this new version of Frama-C. From my point of view, the power of Frama-C could benefit programs using dynamic allocations (like the ones I am working on).